# ajax post response statusCode function not invoked

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

im using this ajax method   for some reason the status code that return from the server after submit  is ignored..

this is what im reciving from the server in the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4241
```

method:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        url : jQuery("#contact-form").attr("action"),
        type : jQuery("#contact-form").attr("method"),
        data : jQuery("#contact-form").serialize(),
        statusCode : {
            200 : (function() {
                alert("yyyyyyyyaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            }),
    400 : (function() {
                alert("eeeerrrrrrrrrr");
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: remove `(` in front of function and remove `)` after the closing curly brace `}` It does not expect a function closure, and on top of that, you're passing nothing into the closure.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't think those parentheses should make a difference. They're redundant in this case, but shouldn't cause a problem.